# MS Access Query / Design

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table with instances of employee events. Each row has an ID, employee name and an eventNumber among other data. I would like to find and count all instances of where “employee name” occurs in this table, thus counting all the events associated with that employee.

If there are 15 unique employees , I suppose I could write 15 separate queries to get this done. But, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Also, I would like to display the total number of events for each employee that gets returned from these queries in another table or visual display of some sorts. This is where I really don’t know what to do as I haven’t used access much but am much more familiar with SQL.

Thanks for everyone who could take some time to chime in with some advice. I appreciate it a lot

Comment: Add some sample data and desired result

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straight-forward in SQL. You can GROUP BY the employee name to get an overall count. Adding GROUP BY to a SQL statement will allow you to perform aggregate functions on one or more columns.  Aggregate functions include COUNT, SUM, MIN, and MAX.

Documentation about GROUP BY can be found here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/group-by-clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0

A couple examples:

This query groups by EmployeeName to get the total count of all rows in table by employee name.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeName
    , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEvents
FROM table
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

Additionally, if you would like to get counts by eventid and employee name, you can group by both employee name and eventid. The query will then show the count of each type of event for each employee name.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeName
    , EventId
    , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEvents
FROM table
GROUP BY 
    EmployeeName
    , EventId
```

If you would like to filter the results so that only one employee, 'Leroy Jenkins' is shown then you can add a WHERE clause as well, like this:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeName
    , COUNT(*) AS NumberOfEvents
FROM table
WHERE EmployeeName = "Leroy Jenkins"
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

---

Responding to @WesG's comment asking for clarification.

The aggregate functions, like COUNT, are "rolling up" several rows in a table and displaying a single value for those rows.  If your SELECT statement does not contain a GROUP BY clause, then the aggregate functions are working on all rows in the table.

When you do have a GROUP BY clause, then the aggregate functions will work on each group of rows that all have the same values in the columns by which you are grouping. Also, if you include a GROUP BY clause, then you **may not** SELECT columns that you are not GROUPing BY.

So, if you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTrailLogs](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [EventId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [WhoDidIt] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WhenOccurredUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EntityPayload] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
```

You could count the total number of rows in the table like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumLogEntries
FROM dbo.AuditTrailLogs
```

If you wanted to count rows by the user who made the entry:

```
SELECT WhoDidIt, COUNT(*) AS NumLogEntries
FROM dbo.AuditTrailLogs
GROUP BY WhoDidIt
```

Then Access is going to split the rows in the table into a number of groups and COUNT will return the number log entries for each distinct value of WhoDidIt in the table.

If you want to see the totals by user who made the log entry **and** event type, then you could group by both columns:

```
SELECT WhoDidIt, EventType, COUNT(*) AS NumLogEntries
FROM dbo.AuditTrailLogs
GROUP BY WhoDidIt, EventType
```

Now, the NumLogEntries in each row of the result set will be the total of each event type that each user made.

Access will complain if you try to do something like this, though:

```
SELECT Id, WhoDidIt, EventType, COUNT(*) AS NumLogEntries
FROM dbo.AuditTrailLogs
GROUP BY WhoDidIt, EventType
```

If you think about it, this query doesn't make sense. The COUNT aggregate functions says you want to roll up multiple rows and display a single value for all those rows, however, you're also asking to see a value that isn't part of a group and is different for each row in the table.

Comment: Good answer...although, since the question is tagged with Access, OP could use Query Designer, which might be easier.

Comment: @Zack Thanks for the feedback. I think that might be a matter of personal preference, though. I've never found Query Designer easier to use than the SQL Editor.

Comment: Personally, I hate the Access SQL editor (no syntax colors, auto-complete, and your formatting is always stripped)---if I ever have to write a SQL query in Access, I'll use a better tool and copy it over (and save the SQL in an external file).

Comment: Agreed. The Access SQL editor is bad compared to a legit editor like SQL Management Studio, but I still prefer typing the exact query I want to using the GUI to construct queries.

Comment: Thanks you all very much for your suggestions and help! The query designer seems like a good tool but I just feel more comfortable writing the query in the sql editor.

Comment: I am continuing to work on this and expand functionality. The queries that @Steven Krise provided worked very well. How could I expand the queries to select more columns but still return a COUNT(*)? I don’t fully understand how count interacts with pulling different amounts of column data

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
select employeeName, count(*) as nbEvents  
from myTable
group by employeeName
```